javafx 23.01 requires different glibc versions to run under linux x64 and aarch64
I recently upgraded the version of javafx to 23.01 and found that it can run normally under x64 Linux after the upgrade, but it cannot run normally under the aarch64 version of Linux, indicating that the glibc version is missing 2.34.
Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:/home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/23.0.1+4/aarch64/libprism es2.so: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6:version 'GLIBc_2.34'not found(required by /home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/23.0.1+4/aarch64/libprism_es2.so)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/23.0.1+4/aarch64/libpism_es2.so: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBc 2.34  not found (required by /home/nusp/.openifx/cache/23.0.1+4/aarch64/libprism es2.so)
    at iava.base/idk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk,internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk,internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
    at java.base/java.lang.classLoader.loadLibrary(classLoader.java:2418)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:852)
    at java.base/java.lang.system.load(System.java:2025)

Through the analysis below, we know that different glibc versions are referenced in prism_es2. How to solve this problem? Is it necessary to have such a high glibc version under aarch64?
Under Linux x64
nm -u libprism_es2.so
w__cxa_finalize
U dlsym
U fprintf_chk
U free
U fwrite

Under Linux aarch64
nm -u libprism_es2.so
w__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17
U dlsym@GLIBC_2.34
U fprintf_chk@GLIBC_2.17
U free@GLIBC_2.17
U fwrite@GLIBC_2.17


The cause of the problem has been basically determined. The main reason is that the dynamic library of jfx based on aarch64 in the maven repository is compiled based on glibc3.4. If a lower version of the glibc version of the operating system is used, it can be used.
I tried using Liberica JDK and it works fine.

Please edit your question and add the exact error you're seeing (as text, not as an image) when you run a JavaFX application on aarch64.  It would also be helpful to include the output of ldd [javafx-home]/lib/*.so | grep libc (again, as text, not as an image).

"Is it necessary to have such a high glibc version" -> if the error message specifically asks for a particular version, then, yes, probably it is necessary to have at least that version.  You could try an earlier version of JavaFX if you needed compatibility with an earlier glibc version.

The prism_es2 library is for the hardware rendering on a GPU.  If the dependency on the later glibc is only to support that, you could try software rendering.

@jewelsea Thank you for correcting the error.

@VGR // sghn1-pc03:/home/nusp/.openjfx/cache % ldd /home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/21.0.1+6/aarch64/*.so | grep libc
ldd: 警告: 你没有执行权限  /home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/21.0.1+6/aarch64/libprism_es2.so' /home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/21.0.1+6/aarch64/libprism_es2.so: /usr/lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/21.0.1+6/aarch64/libprism_es2.so)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffa4cdb000)
ldd: 警告: 你没有执行权限  `/home/nusp/.openjfx/cache/21.0.1+6/aarch64/libprism_sw.so'
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffb2ab9000)

Versioned symbols were meant to solve some compatibility problems. Sadly, they created much more compatibility problems. Also the damage is done, it cannot be undone. You might try to cross-compile javafx for your platform (if you have the source), but it won't be easy.

@jewelsea I tested if I recompile jfx by including a lower version of Glibc, it can works fine.
